# ansible ad-hoc command to run as other user

Tags: ansible

In Ansible documention its stated like :-

**It is also possible to become a user other than root using --become-user:
$ ansible atlanta -a "/usr/bin/foo" -u username --become-user otheruser [--ask-become-pass]**

But when i run this command

```
ansible webservers  -m shell -a "mkdir /tmp/devopstraining" --become-user devops
```

its creating directories with root as owner.If as per documentation if this command is running as devops user then  user devops should be the owner of the directory created.

I am aware that i can use file module to deal with permissions but just curious to know why its not working in above command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
ansible webservers -m shell -a "mkdir /tmp/devopstraining" --become --become-user devops
```